# Is it possible to get a Epson AcuLaser M1400 laser printer working?

Tags: 12.04, printing, epson

I have a new Epson AcuLaser M1400 laser printer and I can't print from Linux (my system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.)
The Aculaser M1200 can use the use the EPL6200L driver from http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/laser/DL1.do.
And the M1400?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that starting with Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr the Epson AcuLaser M1400 is supported by default. Rick Richardsons driver "foo2hbpl" is included in [version "2014-02-09"](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/ChangeLog) as a part of the package "printer-driver-foo2zjs" which is installed by default and provides support for the M1400 since version "2014-01-08".

I've tried it today and it works like a charm! Just plug and play!

If you're using an older version of ubuntu it's possible to manually compile and install the latest driver following the [instructions](http://foo2hbpl.rkkda.com/) from the authors of foo2hbpl.

Answer (score -1):

There's no official driver for M1400, and I haven't found an unofficial yet. Only for Windows. I have the same problem, bought an M1400 so have to use Windows. I have tried several Epson drivers without any results... :(